# Is there a way I can match this ArrayList so that burger1 get in place 1?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I want to match the ArrayList so that right Burgare gets the right position
for example Burgare6 gets position 6 and Burgare2 gets position 2 and so on.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

   List<String> burgare = Arrays.asList("1: Burgare 6", "2: Burgare 7", "3: Burgare 2",
                                        "4: Burgare 1", "5: Burgare 3", "6: Burgare 4", 
                                        "7: Burgare 5");

    System.out.println(burgare);

}
```

Comment: `Burgare` <-- your question is making me hungry.

Comment: ^^ your comment is making me feel Swedish.

Comment: @Hamza why don't you write a custom `Comparator<Burgarare>` and look at `Collections.sort(comparator)`

Comment: @vikingsteve I've try but couldn't fix the problem. how it feels when you feel swedish btw? haha

Comment: Do I understand well that you want to sort the array on the number that follows the 'Burgare ' within each string?

Comment: @RobertKock yes that's what I asked, but it's not an array its a list..

Comment: As @vikingsteve suggested, create a `Comparator<String>` that extracts the numeric value from the strings and compares these numbers. Then call `burgare.sort(myComparator)`

Answer (score 4):

Here you go.

```
    Comparator<String> lastNumberComparator = new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            return Integer.valueOf(o1.split(" ")[2]).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(o2.split(" ")[2]));
        }
    };

    Collections.sort(burgare, lastNumberComparator);
    System.out.println(burgare);
```

Using `String.split(" ")` with spaces is a quick way to split your strings into three tokens "4:", "Burgare", "1" where the last token [2] is the value we use to sort.

Comment: Makes logical sense!! Good answer in my opinion

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use :

```
Collections.sort(burgare, new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String str1, String str2) {
       return Integer.valueOf(str1.split(" ")[2])
                     .compareTo(Integer.valueOf(str2.split(" ")[2]));
    }
});
```

If you are on java-8 then :

```
Collections.sort(burgare, (str1, str2) -> 
         Integer.valueOf(str1.split(" ")[2]).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(str2.split(" ")[2])));
```